# Listar datos en la vista ASP.NET c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

Tengo el siguiente metodo donde traigo los datos de la base de datos

```
//Traer categoria
        public List<categoria> listar()
        {
            var cate = new List<categoria>();

            using (var ctx = new ACME())
            {
                cate = ctx.categoria.ToList();

            }

            return cate;
        }
```

Lo estoy pasando a la vista de la siguiente forma

```
public ActionResult Categoria()
        {
            return View(ct.listar());
        }
```

En la vista añado el modelo (ojo no se si esta bien o mal a este punto)

```
@model LicoreraDist.Models.ACME
```

y por último trato de mostrar los datos que tengo

```
@foreach (var m in Model.categoria)
{
  <ol class="list-group list_of_items">
     <li class='list-group-item'><div class='text_holder'> @m.categoria1<div 
     class='btn-group pull-right'><button class='delete btn btn- 
     warning'>Borrar</button><button class='edit btn btn- 
     success'>Editar</button></div></div><br /></li>
  </ol>
}
```

Según yo "esta bien", pero cuando trato de ver el resultado en la página web me muestra lo siguiente:

```
El elemento de modelo pasado al diccionario es de tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[LicoreraDist.Models.categoria]', pero este diccionario requiere un elemento de modelo de tipo 'LicoreraDist.Models.ACME'.
Descripción: Excepción no controlada al ejecutar la solicitud Web actual. Revise el seguimiento de la pila para obtener más información acerca del error y dónde se originó en el código. 

Detalles de la excepción: System.InvalidOperationException: El elemento de modelo pasado al diccionario es de tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[LicoreraDist.Models.categoria]', pero este diccionario requiere un elemento de modelo de tipo 'LicoreraDist.Models.ACME
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error es si o si en la referencia al modelo en la vista, cual seria mi error en especifico?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es que estas pasando una lista a la vista y estas recibiendo un objeto.

Proba remplazar la linea

```
@model LicoreraDist.Models.ACME
```

Por

```
@model IEnumerable<LicoreraDist.Models.ACME>
```

De esa manera debería funcionar, saludos